# Jquery events do not trigger on content loaded via load()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

What is the appropriate method to get the already-initialized javascript to interact with content loaded using jQuery's load() method?

**Example:** *You have a table with an onclick event for each row, then append() a new row to the table, suddenly the onclick() event does not fire.*

Hopefully it is possible to do this without manually re-initializing every event by writing it into the code that executes the load().

I've looked at $.getScript, live(), and bind() - but haven't gotten any to work. Before I head into hours of trial-and-error, I'd appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the *event* examples you want [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), for example:

```
$("table").delegate("tr", "click", function() {
  //do something, the table row is this, for example:
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

What this does is attach an event handler to the `<table>` element, which listens for events to [bubble up](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) (which elements do regardless of when they were added) and acts upon those events if the element the event came from matches the selector, in this case a `<tr>`.

Or it's an element with an unknown parent, use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) like this:

```
$(".something").live("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

`.live()` works very similarly (in face `.delegate()` uses `.live()` internally), it just attaches to `document`, so a parent higher in the DOM.